How to solve this issue: AttributeError: type object 'SecretFormula' has no attribute 'reveal_formula'
I'm currently enrolled in a Python Fundamentals class (even though my major is culinary arts) as it is required by my school to take some programming course
I am by no means a programmer, let alone (for the life of me) have the ability to understand coding. I'm genuinely still confused even while taking this course. I have this homework that I'm trying to figure out and can't seem to find what the problem is
The homework question is:
In "Breaking Bad," the unique meth formula was crucial to Walter White and Jesse Pinkman's success. Replicate this by securing a secret formula within a Python class SecretFormula, using a private attribute __formula with the value "C10H15N". Implement a class method reveal_formula(cls, passphrase) to disclose the formula only when the correct passphrase "Heisenberg" is used; otherwise, it responds with "Nice try!" Show how to access this formula with both correct and incorrect passphrases.
And this is the code
class SecretFormula:
    __formula = "C10H15N"

@classmethod
def reveal__formula(cls, passphrase):
    if passphrase == "Heisenberg":
        return cls.reveal_formula    
    else:
        return "Nice try!"
    
print(SecretFormula.reveal_formula("Heisenberg"))
print(SecretFormula.reveal_formula("Gus Fring"))

And I keep getting this result:
AttributeError: type object 'SecretFormula' has no attribute 'reveal_formula'

What went wrong? T_T
I can't figure it out!!!

The indentation isn't correct

It is better to use dalaclass

Simply change your identation. This is how to make your code workable:
class SecretFormula:
    __formula = "C10H15N"

    @classmethod
    def reveal__formula(cls, passphrase):
       if passphrase == "Heisenberg":
          return cls.reveal_formula    
       else:
          return "Nice try!"
    
print(SecretFormula.reveal__formula("Heisenberg"))
print(SecretFormula.reveal__formula("Gus Fring"))

